clarification on redis-sentinel read & write
I am trying to write a golang application and its read intensive so I am using redis for caching.
I am planning to use redis sentinel and thinking of making write(to redis) through master and read (from redis) using 3 slaves.
But I am not getting any configs to specifically mention read from slaves and write from master.
I read an article which says by default sentinel will use master for writing and slave for reading, is it true? Can someone confirm please
need to confirm if redis-sentinel by default redirects all the write to master and read to slave
